# Pagination with Consumer API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Is pagination enabled within the Consumer API? I have a case where I need to step through the accounts tied to the Banno and I want to be able to iterate through without all being returned in the response.

I have tried {{consumerUrl}}/users/:userId/accounts?offset=1&limit=1 and the entire results return.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Consumer API endpoints have pagination, but not all of them have pagination.

The [GET /users/{userId}/accounts](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/) endpoint does not have pagination of accounts.

In contrast, the [GET /users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/transactions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/transactions/details/) paginates results for transactions when using the `offset` and `limit` parameters.